# Select only one result field from two joined tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to select only one field from two tables. Instead of `c.cust_name` and `s.supp_name` just only one field name with contend from either `customer` or `supplier` table.

```sql
SELECT o.id, o.order_nr, o.cust_suppl, c.cust_name, s.supp_name
FROM   Orders AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN
       customer AS c ON o.id = c.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
       supplier AS s ON o.id = s.id
```

Current output:

```
id    order_nr   cust_suppl   cust_name   supp_name
1       1100       c            Cust_A      NULL    
2       1101       c            Cust_B      NULL
3       2100       s            NULL        Suppl_A
4       2101       s            NULL        Suppl_B
```

Comment: How do you want to make the selection? Based on `cust_suppl`?

Answer (score 0):

you could decode:

```
SELECT o.id, o.order_nr, o.cust_suppl
       , decode( c.cust_name, null, s.supp_name, c.cust_name )
FROM   Orders AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN
       customer AS c ON o.id = c.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
       supplier AS s ON o.id = s.id
```

or use a case:

```
SELECT o.id, o.order_nr, o.cust_suppl
       , case when c.cust_name is null then s.supp_name else c.cust_name end
FROM   Orders AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN
       customer AS c ON o.id = c.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
       supplier AS s ON o.id = s.id
```